# В чем заключается ошибка при присвоении информации классу

Tags: c++, классы

Вот код примера, не понимаю, что надо сделать в данном этапе:

```
church obj[N] = { 
church("Тодайдзи","Т",220,368.8),
church ("Якусидзи","С",50,54.7),
church("Дайандзи","Д",10,12.2) };
```

Полный текст программы -

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#define N 3             //количество экземпляров класса
using namespace std;
class church {
    char *name;
    char *school;
    unsigned int count;
    float square;

public:
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, church &o1);
    friend istream & operator>>(istream &stream, church &o1);
    friend void shapka(void);
    friend void linebuild(void);
    friend int isvalid(int a, int b);
    church() { square = 0; count = 0; }
    church(const char *a, const char *b, unsigned int &c, float &d);
    void setall(char *a, char *b, unsigned int, float);
    void getall(char *a, char *b, unsigned int &c, float &d);
    void showall(void);
    church operator = (church &o1);
    int    operator == (church &o1);
    church operator + (church &o1);
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream &stream, church &o1) {
    shapka();
    stream << "|" << setw(10) << o1.name << "  |  ";
    stream << setw(5) << o1.school << "|";
    stream << setw(18) << o1.count << "  |";
    stream << setw(17) << o1.square << "  |" << endl;
    linebuild();
    return stream;
}

istream & operator>>(istream &stream, church &o1) {
    cout << "Название, Школа, Количество монахов, Площадь земли: \n";
    stream >> o1.name;
    stream >> o1.school;
    stream >> o1.count;
    stream >> o1.square;
    return stream;
}

int isvalid(int a, int b) {
    if (((a > N - 1) || (a < 0)) || ((b > N - 1) || (b < 0)))
    {
        cout << "Ошибка! Экземпляра с таким индексом не существует.\n";
        _getch();
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a == b)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка! Экземпляр не может быть записан сам в себя.\n";
        _getch();
        return -2;
    }
    return 0;
}

church church::operator + (church &o1) {
    church tr;
    int i, j;
    delete[] tr.name;
    delete[] tr.school;
    tr.name = new char[strlen(name) + strlen(o1.name) + 2];
    strcpy(tr.name, name);
    strcat(tr.name, o1.name);
    tr.school = new char[strlen(school) + strlen(o1.school) + 2];
    strcpy(tr.school, school);
    strcat(tr.school, o1.school);
    tr.count = count + o1.count;
    tr.square = square + o1.square;
    return tr;
}

int church::operator == (church &o1) {
    if (count != o1.count) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; _getch(); }
    else if (ceil(square) != ceil(o1.square)) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; _getch(); }
    else if (strcmp(name, o1.name) != 0) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; _getch(); }
    else if (strcmp(school, o1.school) != 0) { cout << "Данные экземпляры класса не равны."; _getch(); }
    else cout << "Экземпляры класса равны."; _getch();
    return 0;
}

church church::operator = (church &o1) {
    delete[] name;
    delete[] school;
    name = new char[strlen(o1.name) + 2];
    if (!name) {
        cout << "Ошибка! Память не выделена.";
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(name, o1.name);
    school = new char[strlen(o1.school) + 2];
    if (!school) {
        cout << "Ошибка! Память не выделена.";
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(school, o1.school);
    count = o1.count;
    square = o1.square;
    return o1;
}

church::church(const char *a, const char *b, unsigned int &c, float &d) {
    name = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
    strcpy(name, a);
    school = new char[strlen(b) + 1];
    strcpy(school, b);
    count = c;
    square = d;
}

void church::setall(char *a, char *b, unsigned int c, float d) {
    strcpy(name, a);
    strcpy(school, b);
    count = c;
    square = d;
}

void church::showall(void) {
    cout << name << " ";
    cout << school << " ";
    cout << count << " ";
    cout << square << " ";
}

void church::getall(char * a, char *b, unsigned int &c, float &d)
{
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    a = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    b = new char[strlen(school) + 1];
    strcpy(a, name);
    strcpy(b, school);
    c = count;
    d = square;
    cout << a << " ";
    cout << b << " ";
    cout << c << " ";
    cout << d << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}

void shapka(void)
{
    cout << "_______________________________________________________________\n";
    cout << "|         Буддистские монастыри Японии периода Нара           |\n";
    cout << "|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
    cout << "|  Название  | Школа | Количество монахов | Площадь земли(га) |\n";
    cout << "|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
}

void linebuild(void) {
    cout << "\n|-------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
}

int main(void) {
    char *n;
    char *t;
    unsigned int s;
    float h;
    short i, k;
    unsigned int s1;
    short q, q1;

    church obj[N] = { church("Тодайдзи","Т",220,368.8),
              church ("Якусидзи","С",50,54.7),
               church("Дайандзи","Д",10,12.2) };
    system("cls");

    cout.precision(2);
    cout << "Название, Школа, Количество монахов, Площадь земли: \n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        obj[i].showall();
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\nПерегрузка оператора присваивания '='.\n";
    cout << "Введите номера экземпляров класса: заменяемый и заменяющий>\n";
    cin >> q;
    cin >> q1;
    if (isvalid(q, q1) != 0) exit(-1);
    obj[q] = obj[q1];

    cout << "Название, Школа, Количество монахов, Площадь земли: \n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        obj[i].showall();
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\nПерегрузка оператора соответствия '=='.\n";
    cout << "Введите номера экземпляров класса, которые надо сравнить>\n";
    cin >> q;
    cin >> q1;
    if (isvalid(q, q1) != 0) exit(-1);
    obj[q] == obj[q1];

    cout << "\nПерегрузка оператора суммы '+'.\n";
    cout << "Введите номера экземпляров класса, которые надо сложить>\n";
    cin >> q;
    cin >> q1;
    church temp;
    if (isvalid(q, q1) != 0) exit(-1);
    temp = obj[q] + obj[q1];
    cout << "Наименование, Тип, Посевная площадь, Урожайность: ";
    temp.getall(n, t, s, h);

    cout << "\nПерегрузка оператора потокового ввода '>>'.";
    cout << "\nВведите номер экземпляра класса: ";
    cin >> q;
    if ((q > N - 1) || (q < 0)) { cout << "Ошибка! Экземпляра с таким индексом не существует."; _getch(); exit(-1); }
    cin >> obj[q];

    cout << "\nПерегрузка оператора потокового вывода '<<'.";
    cout << "\nВведите номер экземпляра класса: ";
    cin >> q;
    if ((q > N - 1) || (q < 0)) { cout << "Ошибка! Экземпляра с таким индексом не существует."; _getch(); exit(-1); }
    cout << obj[q];

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в вашем конструкторе и его использовании

конструктор:

```
church(const char *a, const char *b, unsigned int &c, float &d);
```

использование:

```
church("Тодайдзи","Т",220,368.8)
```

ссылки на значения c++ не умеет

сделайте так:

```
church(const char *a, const char *b, unsigned int c, float d);
```

Зачем вообще в конструктор передавать по ссылке `int`? Особенно если не собираетесь в них писать.

Даже лучше так:

```
church(const char *a, const char *b, const unsigned int c, const float d);
```

Comment: Что значит *"ссылки на числа c++ не умеет"*? https://godbolt.org/z/KqPhq1

Comment: @dIm0n, в вашем коде ссылка на переменную, а не на значение: `foo(42)` и `foo(x)`, где `foo(int& value)`, это все таки 2 большие разницы или в новом стандарте что-то изменилось? Я наверное неправильно в ответе выразился - ссылка на значение имелось в виду

Comment: Литералы типа `42` можно по ссылке на константу передать `func(const int&)`. Стоит уточнить/убрать эту фразу короче

Comment: @Zhihar, извините, если не трудно ответьте на еще одну загвоздку: `temp = obj[q] + obj[q1];` в данном коде пишет, что отсутствует оператор "=", соответствующий этим операндам. Вроде = и + перегружены, почему такое может возникать, ответьте, пожалуйста

Comment: @t1nzy, во-первых все параметры у операторов сделайте константными, например `church church::operator + (const church &o1)` , а во вторых как-то странно оператор `=` перегружен, - вы возвращаете объект `o1`, вот так сделайте: `church& church::operator = (const church &o1) {... return *this}`. Кстати вместо таких ошибок как у вас лучше выбрасывать исключения - это более правильно в данном случае